# Puberty Blockers for Transgender Youth

Tags: gender-sex-identity, puberty

There have recently been a lot of TV documentaries, dramas, etc. covering the transgender community.  For example, there has recently been a short drama here in the UK called [Butterfly](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7703440/) and there is [I am Jazz](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4523638/) which has so far followed [Jazz Jennings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz_Jennings)' journey for 13 years.

When you look at the process that Jazz Jennings has had to go through (and still is going through) one part of the process was that she was provided [puberty blockers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puberty_blocker) at an early age to prevent the growth of facial hair along with other [effects of male puberty](https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/sexual-health/stages-of-puberty-what-happens-to-boys-and-girls/#first-signs-of-puberty-in-boys).

[Transgender youth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transgender_youth) of both [binary sexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_binary) apply to the medical establishment to gain puberty blockers. The MedicalSciences.SE question [What happens during puberty that causes the deepening & squeaking/cracking (dysphonia) of a male's voice?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/9997) talks about an increase in androgen during puberty and the Wikipedia page on puberty blockers I linked to discusses [Gonadotropin-releasing hormone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonadotropin-releasing_hormone) (GnRH) agonists (e.g., leuprorelin, histrelin) being used.

GnRH activity is very low during childhood, and is activated at puberty or adolescence. Are different blockers used for each binary sex or is the same blocker used for both sex?  How long are these blockers used for? Is it lifetime?